# Template doesn't recognize url name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have these two url confs which refers 2 totally diferent views:

```
 #category
    url(r'^(?P<cat>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.category', name='category'),

    #produt
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product', name='product_detail'),
```

And these links in my templates:

```
{% url 'category' cat='eletronics' %}
{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}
```

But, both links are going to 'category' view, instead of the second going to 'product_detail' view.

I know this because when I click on the second link, django returns a message with an error in a variable name which only exists in the 'category' view.
But, if a change the order in urlconfs, so 'product_detail' view appears before 'category' view, then both links goes to 'product_detail' view.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21801006/351760 which explains an almost identical issue. In your case both '^(?P<cat>[^/]+)/$' and '^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$' will match the same url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the category url like this

> ## category
>
> ```
> url(r'^category/(?P<cat>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.category', name='category'),
> ```

```
#produt
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product', name='product_detail'),
```